# How Do I Go About Code Signing a MacOS Application?

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

There is a professor at the university I work at that has developed a MacOS application he needs to get signed so that it doesn't get blocked by MacOS when users try to run it.  I've gotten his CSR and gotten an Apple Developer cert created for him (using the 'ad hoc' distribution option, which created a cert file named 'distribution.cer').

I've searched the Apple Developer site for information on how to sign the application using XCode, but I can't quite grasp the instructions, not being an XCode user or Apple dev.

From what I can gather, you can also sign an app from a terminal, is that correct? If so, does it only work with *.pkg installers, or also pre-compiled applications (*.app files)?

Answer (score 6):

## Code signing

### Apple Certificates

1. Developer ID Application Certificate - sign a macOS application for distribution outside of the Mac App Store.
2. Developer ID Installer Certificate - sign an application's Installer Package (if any) for distribution outside of the Mac App Store.

### Signing an app

On the command line in a Terminal:

```
codesign -f -o runtime --timestamp -s "Developer ID Application: YOUR NAME (TEAM_ID)" /path/to/bundle.app
```

## Notarization

Be aware that since macOS 10.14.5 (Mojave), software signed with a new Apple developer certificate must be notarized. Code signing is no longer sufficient to bypass Gatekeeper.

Apple's notary service requires you to:

- Enable code-signing for all of the executables you distribute.
- Enable the Hardened Runtime capability for your application and command line targets (include -o runtime option when running the codesign tool).
- Use a “Developer ID” application, kernel extension, or installer certificate for your code-signing signature.
- Include a secure timestamp with your code-signing signature (include the --timestamp option when running the codesign tool).
- Don’t include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true.
- Link against the macOS 10.9 or later SDK.

### Step 1 - Create a disk image

Create a disk image of the app by opening a Terminal and running the following command:

```
hdiutil create -volname MyApp -srcfolder /path/to/MyApp.app -ov -format UDBZ MyApp.dmg
```

### Step 2 - Code sign the disk image

Code sign the disk image by opening a Terminal and running the following command:

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: YOUR NAME (TEAM ID)" --timestamp MyApp.dmg
```

### Step 3 - Generate an app-specific password

Generate an app-specific password, refer to [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397). Note: this is a password that will be specific to the notarization application (xcrun altool) and not to the application being notarized. You therefore only need to do this once, but make sure you copy the generated password and save it somewhere.

### Step 4 - Upload disk image to notary service

Note: When you notarize the container disk image, altool also notarizes the application inside, so you can skip the step of notarizing the application itself.

Upload the disk image file to the Apple notary service by opening a Terminal and running the following command:

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id "<your identifier>" -u "<your email>" -p "<app-specific pwd>" -t osx -f /path/to/MyApp.dmg
```

The primary-bundle-id helps you keep track of automated correspondence from the notarization service. The value you give doesn’t need to match the bundle identifier of the submitted app or have any particular value. It only needs to make sense to you. The notarization service includes the value whenever it emails you regarding the given altool submission.

If the upload is successful you should receive output similar to the following:

```
No errors uploading 'MyApp.dmg'.
RequestUUID = 3af4e56f-162b-75bc-827f-7233f92bf20c
```

### Step 5 - Check the notarization process

The notarization process generally takes less than 15 minutes, so you may want to check its progress from time to time by opening a Terminal and running the following command:

```
xcrun altool --notarization-history 0 -u "<your email>" -p "<app-specific pwd>"
```

When the notarization process completes successfully the above command will return information similar to the following:

```
Notarization History - page 0

Date                      RequestUUID                          Status    Status Code Status Message   
------------------------- ------------------------------------ ------- ----------- ---------------- 
2019-12-08 06:24:03 +0000 3af4e56f-162b-75bc-827f-7233f92bf20c success 0           Package Approved
```

You should also receive an email from Apple similar to the following for a successful notarization:

```
Dear <First_Name>,
Your Mac software has been notarized. You can now export this software and distribute it directly to users.
Bundle Identifier: com.example.MyApp.001
Request Identifier: 3af4e56f-162b-75bc-827f-7233f92bf20c
For details on exporting a notarized app, visit Xcode Help or the notarization guide.
Best Regards,
Apple Developer Relations
```

### Step 6 - Staple the ticket to the disk image

The notarization process produces a ticket that tells Gatekeeper that your application is notarized. After notarization completes successfully, the next time any user attempts to run your application on macOS 10.14 or later, Gatekeeper will find the ticket online. This includes users who downloaded your application before notarization.

After step 5 receives the "Package Approved" status message, you should also attach the ticket to the disk image file using the stapler tool, so that future distributions include the ticket. This ensures that Gatekeeper can find the ticket even when a network connection is not available.

To staple the ticket to the disk image file, open a Terminal and run the following command:

```
xcrun stapler staple /path/to/MyApp.dmg
```

If the command completes successfully, the output should be similar to:

```
Processing: /Path/to/MyApp.dmg
Processing: /Path/to/MyApp.dmg
The staple and validate action worked!
```

### Step 7 - Verify notarization of the disk image

To verify the notarization of the disk image, open a Terminal and run the following command:

```
spctl -a -vv -t install MyApp.dmg
```

A successful verification of the notarization process should produce output similar to the following:

```
MyApp.dmg: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: <Developer Name> (<TEAM_ID>)
```

### Step 8 - Verify notarization of the application

To verify the notarization of the application, install the application, open a Terminal and run the following command:

```
spctl -a -vv /Applications/MyApp.app
```

A successful verification of the notarization process should produce output similar to the following:

```
/Applications/MyApp.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: <Developer Name> (<TEAM_ID>)
```

Important: test the application by putting it in the Applications directory. It's treated differently by the Gatekeeper when in the "installed" location.

Alternatively, the Apple-recommended way to verify the notarization of an application is to open a Terminal and run the following command:

```
xcrun stapler validate MyApp.app
```

A successful verification of the notarization process should produce output similar to the following:

```
Processing: MyApp.app
The validate action worked!
```

Comment: This is the reason why nobody wants to develop open source apps for Mac.